# Fillable pdf green or red Flag buttons

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf-generation, adobe

a PDF form,  The last column (Flag) - I would like some type of button in each row that can be turned from green to red if the person thinks it is a serious issue.
regards

Answer (score 0):

Create your button so that it is Green, then have it run a Java Script when pushed.

The following code will then turn it Red

```
(this.getField("Button")).fillColor = ["RGB", 1, 0, 0];
```

"Button" being the name of the button in question.

If you want it to toggle between green and red when clicked, then that is a little more involved. You will need somewhere to store the current colour (I have used a hidden text field called 'label') and then use the following javascript when the button is pushed...

```
switch (this.getField("label").value) {
    case "GREEN":
        (this.getField("Button")).fillColor = ["RGB", 1, 0, 0];
        this.getField("label").value="RED";
        break;
    case "RED":
        (this.getField("Button")).fillColor = ["RGB", 0, 1, 0];
        this.getField("label").value="GREEN";
        break;
}
```

This could easily be adapted to make the button (or any other object) change colour based on the value of some other field elsewhere in the form.

Comment: You're very welcome, please don't forget to accept the answer if it works for you. I also made a slight edit to correct a mistake - RGB values are 0-1 rather than 0-256. Cheers.